# In SVN Eclipse, is “Update to head” dangerous?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

I would like to update my current project regarding the remote repository, since my selected project is now out of date. In eclipse there is the option “Update to head”. Is this dangerous, so can I change my remote repository?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "remote repository" since there's only one repository. Subversion is not git.

Answer (score 1):

Updating your Subversion working copy is normally never dangerous. However, if your local uncommitted modifications conflict with changes incoming from the repository, then you will need to resolve these conflicts. If you have doubts about your expertise with version control, make a backup of your working copy.

BTW, I do not know whether SVN plug-ins for Eclipse provide decent and modern conflict resolution tools. I think that those plug-ins do not support modern SVN conflict resolution interface, and using the `svn.exe` client to solve potential conflicts in interactive mode can be a preferable option.